# How to modify the offset of an instance previously 'naturaly rotated' with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms, instances

I want to create a little sphere with big towers of diferent height above.

First I create the tower with a height of 11 floors.
After I create a sphere.
With Geometry Nodes I place the towers above the surface of the sphere.

Now I want to randomly modify the height of the towers.
My idea is to use the offset property to move the tower inside the sphere to hide certains floors randomly.

[image: The sphere with the towers above]

*The sphere with the towers above.*
[image: The Nodes to place the towers]

*The Nodes to place the towers.*
[image: The Nodes to change randomy the offset]

*The Nodes to change randomy the offset.*

When I place this nodes als the towers change the height.
How can I do to randomly change the height of each instance?

Thanks and sorry for my english :(

Comment: [Translate Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/translate_instances.html) (with *Local Space* enabled) after [Instance on Points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/instance_on_points.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, all you would need to do is apply the `Translate Instances` node after the `Instance on Points` node, feed it a random value, and enable the *Local Space* option:

[image]

This will perform a transformation on the Z axis while maintaining the current rotation of each object.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Really easy ! When you know of course.
Thanks very much :)